# Can you pass a parameter to a Page using RunObject?

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, businesscentral

I have a role center page which I've set up with a few actions. Clicking the action will open a list page which is pre filtered (using RunPageView). I would like to pass the filter to the list page somehow but cant seem to find the answer out there.

The role center page is set up like this:

```
page 50125 "My Role Center"
{
    PageType = RoleCenter;
    Caption = 'My Role Center';
    Extensible = true;

    layout
    {
        ...
    }

    actions
    {
        area(Processing)
        {
            action(MyAction1)
            {
                Caption = 'My Action 1';
                RunPageView = where("Type" = filter('Type1'));
                RunObject = Page "My List Page";
            }
            action(MyAction2)
            {
                Caption = 'My Action 2';
                RunPageView = where("Type" = filter('Type2'));
                RunObject = Page "My List Page";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The list page it opens up is something like this:

```
page 50126 "My List Page"
{
    Caption = 'My Page';
    ApplicationArea = All;
    PageType = List;

    layout
    {
        ...
    }

    trigger OnOpenPage()
    begin
       // I would like to get the filter here if possible
    end;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stumbled upon what is known as `FilterGroups`.

Filtering records can be done in various groups. This can be done either through code or it is done automatically in some situations.

The default `FilterGroup` is 0 which means that in the `OnOpenPage` trigger you will only see filters from `FilterGroup` 0 when you call e.g. `GetFilter(...)`.

`RunPageView` uses `FilterGroup` 3 which means you can get to your filters like this:

```
trigger OnOpenPage()
var
    TypeFilter: Text;
begin
    Rec.FilterGroup(3);
    TypeFilter := Rec.GetFilter(Type);
    Rec.FilterGroup(0);
end;
```

You should always reset the `FilterGroup` to 0 to avoid any unintended behavior.

The full list of available FilterGroups can be found [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/record/record-filtergroup-method).

Comment: Thanks so much, your suggestion about FilterGroups got me on the right track so its all good now. I can get the parameter using Rec.GetFilter now.